# Find the value of $\tan^{-1} ( \sin(\pi/3))$ in the third quadrant

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $\tan^{-1} ( \sin(\pi/3))$ in the third quadrant

My workings:

The principal value of $\tan^{-1} : [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

I also recognised that $\sin(\pi/3) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, its a special angle

So, $\tan \theta = \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} $

Is this just as simple as typing into the calculator $\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 0.7137$ or is there a way to solve it using co-function identities? I do not think there is a way to solve this using co-function identities, as I cannot change $ \sin \theta$ into $\tan \theta$

Is the way I am solving it correct?

Comment: I deleted my answer since by the usual convention the arctangent function is defined so that its range is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, which means that there is no solution in the third quadrant.  We could define a new function $g: \mathbb{R} \to (\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ such that $g(x) = \theta$ if $\theta$ is the unique angle in $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ such that $\tan\theta = x$.  The function $g$ would be an inverse function whose range is the third quadrant.  If $f: \mathbb{R} \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is defined by $f(x) = \arctan x$, then $g(x) = f(x) + \pi$.

Comment: To follow up, what was the exact wording of the question?   Were you asked to define the arctangent function so that the range was in the third quadrant?